# Limit Running Threads to one in ASP.NET Core 6 using TaskScheduler

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core 6 application. The user upload files and we do process those files.

Processing the files is a CPU and memory extensive operation. We are planning to take these operations outside of our main application, but until we do that we decided to try to run the task in background after uploading the file, and send email when the operation is done.

So the process of file is:

```cs
public async Task ProcessFile(string filePath, ...) 
{
    var stage1 = await ProcessStage1(...);
    var stage2 = await ProcessStage2(...);
    await SendEmail(..);
}
```

From the upload the file we run the task.run

```cs
public async Task UploadFile(Stream stream....)
{
   // .... uploading the file 

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
     ProcessFile(....);
   })
}
```

Because the process is heavy, so it is consuming lots of memory, so we decided to limit the process to one file at one time by limiting the threads to only two or one.

Reading the example in [.NET TaskScheduler to limit the threads to one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-6.0#examples) , I implemented the code mentioned in the example, and I added the custom `TaskScheduler` as singleton as the following:

```cs
public interface IProcessFileFactory {
 public TaskScheduler Scheduler { get; }
    public TaskFactory Factory { get; }
} 

public ProcessFileFactory: IProcessFileFactory 
{
    public TaskScheduler Scheduler { get; }
    public TaskFactory Factory { get; }

    public ProcessFileFactory()
    {
      Scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2);
      Factory = new TaskFactory(Scheduler);
    }
   
    // then add it as singlton in DI
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(TaskScheduler, LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler)
    }

    /// and then use it 

    IProcessFileFactory.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    ProcessFile(...),
    ..., IProcessFileFactory.Scheduler);
```

And I tried it in a different way

```cs
 Services.AddSignlton<TaskScheduler>(x => new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler (2) );

// and then use it
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() {
     ProcessFile() 
    },
CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler);
```

Both cases didn't work, and it is processing files for more than 2.

Comment: I suggest you to use bulkhead pattern implemented in the Polly library https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#bulkhead

Comment: Thanks a lot @mtkachenko for your input.
I looked at their implementation, and they are using SemaphorSlim. I had that on my radar, but was not preferring to go there as I don't understand it well, and I don't understand what will happen when we are waiting for a metaphor and it takes a minute to come.
my first test shows it block other uploads, and other uploads will be blocked and sometimes the timeout will kill it.
It might be there is a way to use it and get the results that I am hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are planning to take these operations outside of our main application...

[That is the correct solution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as I describe on my blog.

> ... TaskScheduler ...

`TaskScheduler` is a low-level primitive that isn't usually used with `async` code. It sounds like you just need a [queue service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). As long as you process the work items one at a time, nothing more complex is necessary.

As a reminder, in-memory queues such as channels are not durable and thus you can lose work on any application shutdown. A proper solution uses a durable queue, and (preferably) a separate worker process outside your main application to perform the operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen_Cleary. I have been reading your book  (concurrency in c# second edition) to find answer.
Thanks  I will look at the link you mentioned, and your blog post.

Comment: This works like a sharm.